# How to curve lines between points on a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, origin-destination, curvature

I'm trying to curve the lines between points on a [RaphaelJS map](http://raphaeljs.com/world/) like [Tata Communications](http://www.tatacommunications.com/map/intranet-map-application-v1.0.swf?map_link=map-data/swf/gfp-map-v6.3-v1.swf&preview_map_link=map-data/swf/map-preview.swf&legend_link=map-data/swf/gfp-legend-v1.1.swf&layersLink_str=map-data/xml/gfp_map_layers_v1.0.xml&allowFullScreen=true&useMiniSkin=true) - but how did they do it? What sort of mathematics lie behind these curves - unless ofcourse they're all manually drawn?

Some dude told me [Catmull-Rom Splines](http://zreference.com/raphael-2-0-catmull-rom-splines/), but those will only smoothen lines, not curve them.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you zoomed into that map to see details?  Look at Miami and the Bahamas for instance: it is clear that even the endpoints of the curves are manually placed and edited.

Comment: Might tmcw's solution about using arc.js at least get me close though?

Comment: Not even remotely: it's for computing geodetically *straight* lines, not curves.  Merely as an example of the myriad approaches to this, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/curved-point-to-point-route-maps

Answer (score 1):

See [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) for a semi-automated solution.