# Draw two separate lines from A to B and B to A

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, r, line, polyline-creation

I have an Origin-Destination table like this

```
Origin Destination Value
A B 10
B A 100
A C 120
...
```

For all the locations A, B, C... I have another table indicating their location (Lat and Lon)

Is there any way to draw two separate lines between A and B so that I can visualize the directionality and distinguish the flow volume between these two places?

Thanks!

Comment: Some of the answers given to the related question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/curved-point-to-point-route-maps might naturally solve this because the arcs they draw are asymmetrical.  Because that is somewhat of an accidental feature of these solutions, they ought to be considered work-arounds rather than primary answers to your question, but perhaps they might be helpful in some cases.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your suggestions. I was thinking a way to solve this: 1) Define a function DrawArcBetween(Origin, Destination, arc) 2) Define a Hashset<Destination,Origin> 3) If the destination, origin pair can be found in the Hashset, take the negative of the arc. Don't know if there would be simpler way to solve this...

Comment: There are simpler ways. For instance, define an asymmetric arc-drawing function. (*Mathematica* does this by default for directed graphs, incidentally.) For example, to draw an arc from A to B, first jog a little to the left at A, head towards the left of B, then jog (towards the right) back to B at the end. That algorithm when applied from B to A will produce a different parallel arc between A and B. I have illustrated this in an answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48467/what-is-symmetric-property-for-stationary-distribution/48522#48522.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in ArcGIS or R?

Comment: @Andy R should be fine for me.

Comment: Do you need these points and lines in a GIS package? Or is this purely for visualisation?

Answer (score 2):

**FlowMapper Plugin for QGIS (v0.2.3)** can exactly do what you want. Using a white space delineated interaction matrix (txt) and a set of coordinates (txt) you can create two way flow line segments.

e.g.
Assuming that we have 3 nodes A, B, C

txt input coordinates file (long, lat)
40.789 30.987
40.123 30.456
39.678 29.741

txt interaction square matrix (From node -> To node)
0 200 300
50 0 150
10 20 0

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/

Comment: Note that with three nodes, the O-D matrix would have *six* records, not three, because the *order* of the points matters here.  I therefore have the same question for you as I had for RyanDalton: why wouldn't this just create two coincident features for each O-D pair? Is there some setting that can be changed to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS, you can accomplish this by using the [XY To Line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000tv000000) tool to accomplish this task, with a little work.

You'll first need to create a new featureclass that has both the Origin & Destination Lat/Long, then you can use **XY to Line** tool to build the geodesic lines between them, using something similar to the code snippet on the help page:

```
arcpy.XYToLine_management(input_table,out_lines,
                         "LOND1","LATD1","LOND2",
                         "LATD2","GEODESIC","idnum")
```

You can also accomplish this by running the tool in ModelBuilder if you don't want to deal with Python.

Comment: Why wouldn't this just create two perfectly coincident features for each O-D pair?

Comment: yes, it does, actually, create coincident lines between the O-D pair.  But it does create two lines, going in both directions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the spirit of the question includes being able to "visualize ... and distinguish" between the two lines.  Coincidence prohibits that.