# Lines as Great circles on a map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, line, great-circle

How can I get line features to appear as great circles on a map, instead of straight lines?

Comment: You want to display a line as a circle? Considered computing the centroid of the line and buffer/increase it to your liking?

Comment: You need to give more information, in order to answer your question. What software are you using? How are you drawing these lines? How did you generate the lines?

Comment: if you are interested in doing your mapping in R, check out this blog post:
http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/

Comment: I'm using Quantum GIS, and what I was hoping to get is when I draw a line between two points on a map, it would show as a great circle line (a curved line, depending on the current projection), and not as a straight line on the screen.

Comment: You might find either of these posts helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84443/what-is-this-postgis-query-doing-to-show-great-circle-connections?lq=1 or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/curved-point-to-point-route-maps

Comment: Using QGIS, you will find an answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86639/draw-great-circle-rays-from-a-single-point-along-specific-directions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All comments look great but let me draw your attention to new [`Beeline`](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Beeline-master/) plugin (Oct.2017~).

Probably no explanations are needed. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Actually, I find the [Shape Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/) plugin to better suite my needs, as it converts line features to great circle arcs.

Comment: @user15749 thanks for Shape Tools mention. Saved me a lot of time.