# How to offset/displace overlapping lines in a web map?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, geometry, google-maps-api

I have a dataset of points representing a To/From status - something like distribution centres and delivery addresses.

When the user clicks on a point I'd like to show the relationships between this point and its related points using lines. Eg when clicking on an address, show the path to the delivery centre.

This works fine, except when there are multiple overlapping lines. In this situation I'm looking for a method to separate the lines automatically, so that it's clear there are multiple lines, and each can be interrogated.

I've put a simple example on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slead/WW5h2/) - this sample creates 5 overlapping lines. Is there any way to displace them automatically, while retaining the start and end nodes?

[image]

This is the effect I'm aiming for, ideally handling multiple overlapping lines automatically:

[image]

This example uses Google Maps, but an answer in ArcGIS Server's JS API would be acceptable too.

Comment: [The solution I posted to a related question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5224/664) would, with minor modification, work in this instance.  Spread the arcs across a narrow range of equally-spaced angles.

Answer (score -1):

If you apply a function jitter to your data points, it will provide that effect.

Comment: This approach, although clever, looks doomed. The question explicitly asks to *keep* ("retain") the positions of the start and end nodes. If you jitter them so little that they will appear to be retained, then that won't resolve the overlap of the lines; but if you jitter them enough to resolve the overlap, it would be difficult to construe that as "retaining" the points.