# Network Diffusion Map in Carto?

Tags: carto

I am working on an interactive map which I envision to have a similar structure to diffusion networks. I have data to pin point an event and I would like to show those involved with said event, and display this data year by year.

These networks are normally shown in abstract space and can be created in statistical software. I was wondering if there is any map services or current programs that allow for a geographic analysis of this sort.

**Some examples:**

http://thebritishgeographer.weebly.com/the-spread-of-disease-and-its-management.html
(under HIERARCHICAL DIFFUSION)

Diffusion Networks and Cascade Analytics
http://people.tuebingen.mpg.de/diffusion-networks-wsdm14/

Answer (score 1):

In order to create something similar in CartoDB you'll need two layers: one with the points (cities in the first example) and another one for the arrows (you'd need to create lines).

You can show the bubbles bigger or smaller by using, for example, the Bubble wizard, or by simply customizing your CartoCSS to plot the size of the bubbles different in size.

In order to create the lines, you can do it in a programatic way by using a SQL query and the [ST_MakeLine function in PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html). You can find a similar tutorial [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/gps_track.html), but in your case it would be different because you need to add lines between pairs of elements. One more example probably more accurate in this question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138607/create-links-between-points-on-cartodb) answered by Paul Ramsey, PostGIS core developer :-)

This creation of the line depends a lot on the structure of your data table, so if you have specific details for it we could help you further.

If you're not familiar with CartoDB yet, I recommend you to take a look at the [CartoDB Academy](http://academy.cartodb.com/).